# Python sqlite3's executemany function returns ValueError

Tags: python, sqlite

I have the following python code which is part of a larger for loop, where I am inserting latlon data along with weather data for future inspection. Note that I am checking if the data at that iteration is float64 (since it could also be masked, where I'd rather skip).

```
values = (lat_db,lon_db,sst_db)
        if type(sst_db) != numpy.float64:
            continue

        c.executemany('INSERT INTO current VALUES(?,?,?)',values)
```

The table itself was created through these lines:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('sst.db')
c = conn.cursor()

# Create the database table.
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE current
             (lat real, lon real, sst real)''')
```

Upon running my script, I get the following error:

```
    c.executemany('INSERT INTO current VALUES(?,?,?)',values)
ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`execute` expects a *sequence* of parameters.

`executemany` works for multiple executions, so it expects a sequence of sequences of parameters:

```
values = ((lat_db,lon_db,sst_db),)
c.executemany('INSERT INTO current VALUES(?,?,?)',values)
```

This makes sense only if you want to insert multiple records:

```
values = ((lat_db1, lon_db1, sst_db1),
          (lat_db2, lon_db2, sst_db2))
c.executemany('INSERT INTO current VALUES(?,?,?)', values)
```

Comment: should I adapt my create table statement to have float instead of real values?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the declared column type, which [has no effect](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) anyway. You are supposed to execute the code shown before trying to use `float64` values together with the `sqlite3` module.

Comment: I have done the changes, but the error persists. I have also changed the create table statement just to be sure, same thing.

Comment: Sorry, `float64` already is compatible by default. The error was raised because `lat_db` is not a sequence.